# How to remove Wikipedia nested tags using Perl

Tags: perl, parsing, wikipedia, wikimedia

I have wikimedia tags in a text file. I need to get rid of these tags from starting to ending even when nesting. I'm using Perl.

I'm facing a difficulty in nested tags. I'll give two examples of these tags that I could not to remove.

Example 1:

```
{{ text
text
text {{ text
text}}
text }}
```

Example 2:
instead of "{{" in example 1, we have the tags "]]".

```
[[ text
text [[ text
text]]
text ]]
```

I hope someone to pinpoint me to solve this issue

Comment: What is your desired result and what have you tried?

Comment: Do you just need to remove the brackets, or the things in the brackets too?

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at [Can I use Perl regular expressions to match balanced text?](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq6.html#Can-I-use-Perl-regular-expressions-to-match-balanced-text%3f)

Answer (score -1):

```
s/{{|}}//g;
```

will erase the `{{` or `}}`